# Guessing values in real time based on previous values

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, smoothing, smooth-streaming

[image: smoothing values]

The following applies to c# .net 4. I am looking for a c# code.

(Figure 1) I have different values, for instance 700, 712, 703 and 720. dt1 is for instance 30ms, dt2 may be 9ms. What matters is that dt1 to dtn is not constant.

(Figure 2) The time axis

(Figure 3) This is what I want, values for a constant time gap tc of roughly 17ms. x1 to xn are the values a variable consists of, ie:

```
x(t(x1)) = x1
x(t(x2)) = x2
...
x(t(xn)) = xn
```

How do I determine x1 to xn in real time? So let's say the current time is dt1+dt2+somewhere within dt3. I do not know when dt3 will be finished(even though previous dt were in between 9ms and 30ms) and what value there will be. How could I guess a value for x4 that takes previous changes into account?

How do I smooth the values of (Figure 1) at the same time for them to be - say - 700 - 708 - 712 - 720, ie remove the jitter?

Comment: not really sure this is a question for StackOverflow C#

Comment: Do you want to interpolate your signal? From non uniform distributed samples do you need to obtain uniform distributed samples?

Comment: You should have answered your other question, keeping information together, instead of creating a new one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700219/how-to-smooth-mouse-movement/10703081#comment13899593_10703081

Comment: This is an algorithm question rather than a programming question.  There isn't a good maths network on StackExchange, so haven't suggested moving it yet.  And C# is completly irrelevant to the answer

Comment: Try reading about differentials and smoothing, there are a examples of how it is used to approximate results.  The papers though tend to be very heavily maths based.

Comment: It does apply to c# as I am programming in this language and I am not interested to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @Adriano "Do you want to interpolate your signal? From non uniform distributed samples do you need to obtain uniform distributed samples?" Yes.

Comment: Should it be done in real-time or it can be done in post-processing when you have all the data? For real-time it's not really trivial (take a look here for algorithm: http://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/matlab/rastamat/). If it can be done in post-processing it'll be much more easy (you just need a good interpolation class, take a look to ALGLIB or NMath).

Comment: "How do I determine x1 to xn in real time?" is the question. Are you sure there is no c# implementation of this?

Answer (score 0):

Gonna take a shot at this (poorly worded sequence of operations following):

> 1. read current X (let's call it Xt)
> 2. perform whatever operation you need with Xt
> 3. store Xt
> 4. read new X (let's call it X2)
> 5. if abs(X1-X2) is less than a certain tolerance, discard X2 and make it = X1
>
>    if X2 > X1, discard the value of X2 and make it = X1+K
>
>    if X2 < X1, discard the value of X2 and make it = X1-K
> 6. set Xt = X2
> 7. goto 2

Just a very rough idea of "smoothing" where you ignore the value and only care for the orientation of the "movement" of your x.

Comment: That could work. But as soon as the values are more or less similar, I need the absolute position.

Comment: @RichartBremer Updated to cover that condition aswell

Answer (score 0):

I think There Are Two Solutions As I Understood Your Questions

1. Pass Variables by reference e.g : x(ref t(ref (x1))
2. declare Your Variables  as static variable e.g : static x1

Comment: are we talking about the same problem here?